# Get a date when a string is attached to it

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a list of dates with a working crew added to them...

```
07/19/15254A
07/21/15254B
07/22/15254A
07/22/15254B
etc...
```

What I need to do is be able to enter just a date to search by/for such as
`07/20/15` and return the first date from the list above that matches or is the next available date. This `07/20/15` should return `07/21/15254B`.

Comment: Dont store more than one information in one column. This should be two columns. One `date`/`datetime` and another `varchar`/`char`.

Comment: Too late for that, the table is ages old and updated/used by a number of other systems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
select * from tablename where convert(datetime,left(Columnname,8))=CONVERT(datetime,'15/07/20',11)
```

Comment: I got around the error but get a return of 07/20/15, it should be 07/21/15.